# Counting the number of multi-byte characters

Tags: php, html, libreoffice

I have text containing multi-byte characters as shown:

> 위키백과, 백과사전.
>
> 대수(λ -, lambda -)는 함. 1930년대 다. 함수 s(x, y) = x*x + 입력 x 것이다. x ↦ x 와 y
>   ↦ y 는 변수의 이름은. 또한 (x, y) ↦ x*x + y*y 와 (u, v) ↦ u*u + v*v 는.123456

In a word processor, it gives me a character count of 148.

On a HTML form encoded in UTF-8, it uses up a `TEXTAREA` field with attribute of `maxlength = 150`.

Using the PHP function `mb_strlen($_POST['text'],'UTF-8')`, it returns a value of **152**.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which Word processor?  Maybe they don't count newlines as characters?

Comment: @ Yzmir Ramirez, libreoffice writer. You are right, it doesn't count newlines. Then why is there a difference between HTML and PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to say they all are correct.

With no line endings it is 148.

With line endings it is 150 or 152 depending on the encoding (Windows uses 2 characters per line ending).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand. You mean PHP counted two extra `\n`s, HTML counted one?

Comment: In Windows a newline are two characters `\n\r`, but on a Mac OS X and *nix machines its `\n`, and `\r` for Mac OS (up to 9) if memory served me correctly.  History of the newline http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: @ Yzmir Ramirez, I see.. I am using Linux.

Comment: @BenHuh if you insert another line what is the output? 153 and 156?

Comment: @ Pubby, if I increase maxlength to 152, I am able to enter two newlines, my PHP count will rise to 156 but my word processor count will remain as 148.

Comment: I guess HTML counts a newline as one character, PHP counts it as two and word processor doesn't count newlines at all.

Comment: Correcting my comment above `\r\n` for Windows, not `\n\r`!